# Does "Exception" capture all other "Concrete Exceptions"

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I'm having issues with tweepy while running the Streaming API, but my question isn't directly related only to tweepy.

I have been getting multiple exceptions and I thought I could "catch/pass" for the time being, as a temporary solution, until I find out where the problem is.

As of now, tweepy has been throwing 5 different errors `(IncompleteRead, ProtocolError, UnicodeDecodeError, AttributeError, TypeError)`, and they're all resulting from the filter to the API not from me obtaining the data.

The line they all have in common from the Traceback is:

```
twitterStream.filter(locations=[-125.22, 31.61, -104.86, 49.0, -104.86, 26.11, -66.94, 49.03])
```

`IncompleteRead` and `ProtocolError` are related to different packages that tweepy uses. But `(UnicodeDecodeError, AttributeError, TypeError)` are [Concrete Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/exceptions.html#concrete-exceptions).

**My question:**

Am I right to assume that the [Exception](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/exceptions.html#Exception) base class can capture all those (the last 3)? Or is that incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for Exception states

> All built-in, non-system-exiting exceptions are derived from this class

so the Exception base class should be able to capture those, as they are non-system-exiting (an example of a system-exiting exception is SystemExit). You can test this quickly if you'd like:

```
try:
    raise AttributeError
except Exception:
    print("We caught an exception!")
```

That said, blindly capturing the Exception base class is generally considered a Bad Idea because you will likely end up capturing exceptions that you won't want to.